# What's the difference between 'adb push' and 'adb install'?

Tags: adb

Will `adb push` only copy the file into the target location whereas `adb install` copies the file into the target location *and* also sets the proper permission for you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

More specifically

```
adb push [file] [path]
```

will take [file] from the PC and copy it to [path] on the android device.

```
adb install [apkfile]
```

will copy [apkfile] from the pc into `/data/app/` on the android device.

The main difference being that push will let you specify where you want the file to go on the device, and install puts it in a known location (the location "installed" apps exist in).

Answer (score 15):

`adb push` will copy any file to the phone, whereas `adb install` will only accept an apk file, and will install it onto the device.

Comment: Does "install" mean anything more than copying the apk to /data/app/ ?